# Node.JS - Node-PowerShell return value

Tags: node.js

I am using a node-powershell module from https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell.

```
var shell = require('node-powershell'); 
PS = new shell('echo "node-powershell is awesome"'); 
PS.on('output', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
PS.on('end', function(code) {
    //optional callback 
    //Do Something 
});
```

I am trying to return data from a function and assign it to a variable $returneddata:

```
function getData()
{
var shell = require('node-powershell'); 
PS = new shell('echo "node-powershell is awesome"', {debugMsg: false});
PS.on('output', function(data){
    return data;
});
PS.on('end', function(code) {

});

}

var $returneddata = getData();
```

But it does not assign it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not seeing the data because your return statement is returning it to the wrong caller :) `PS.on('output' ...` is registering a callback function for an event. The provided function will then be called by the event emitter when the event is raised. Therefore, the value returned by this callback is actually being returned to the event emitter, who doesn't care about your return value, rather than the caller of `getData`.

To correct the issue, you should provide a callback of your own, try this:

```
function getData(callback) {
    var shell = require('node-powershell'); 
    PS = new shell('echo "node-powershell is awesome"', {debugMsg: false});
    PS.on('output', function(data){
        return callback(null, data);
    });
    PS.on('end', function(code) {

    });
}

getData(function onGetData(err, data) {
    // do stuff with the returned data here
});
```

As an aside, you may not need the `err` parameter, but error-first callbacks are the convention in node. You should probable add `PS.on('error' ...` if the module supports it...